# Google Sign In Popup window not showing on mobile - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building a web app that uses Firebase Authentication and I implemented the Google Sign In with the function **signInWithPopup**. But while on a pc browser the popup is shown correctly, on mobile it immediately closes or doesn't event open and I can't find anywhere on the internet why it happens.
The whole project is set up with create-react-app.

Answer (score 0):

signInWithPopup() is for the browser, if you're running Andriod, you need to call signInWithCredential.

```
signInWithGoogle() {
    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      return this.gl.login(['email', 'public_profile']).then(res => {
        const googleCredential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
        return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
      })
    }
    else {
      return this.afAuth.auth
        .signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())
        .then(res => console.log(res));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for the trivial question but what is **this.gl**?